# Does AWS Elasticsearch snapshot contains data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

I was reading upon the AWS documentation on Elasticsearch and in the latest versions they take snapshot of the AWS ES Cluster every 1 hour and store it in S3.

This can prove super useful in terms of recovery.

But I could not find if this snapshot just contains the cluster information or the data as well ?

Can someone confirm with if it stores the data as well or just the cluster information ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html):

> On Amazon Elasticsearch Service, snapshots come in two forms: automated and manual.
>
> - Automated snapshots are only for cluster recovery. You can use them to restore your domain in the event of red cluster status or other data loss. Amazon ES stores automated snapshots in a preconfigured Amazon S3 bucket at no additional charge.
> - Manual snapshots are for cluster recovery or moving data from one cluster to another. As the name suggests, you have to initiate manual snapshots. These snapshots are stored in your own Amazon S3 bucket, and standard S3 charges apply. If you have a snapshot from a self-managed Elasticsearch cluster, you can even use that snapshot to migrate to an Amazon ES domain.

This will support cluster recovery for both and data migration from a manual snapshot. Any networking or configuration of the cluster from within the Elasticsearch service itself is managed entirely via the AWS API so these should be managed via infrastructure as code (such as [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) or [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/)).

Comment: Thanks. The use case is if my cluster goes down, I will need to recover the data. So what Was thinking is creating the cluster via CF/TF. And then create the indexes and copy the data from the old snapshots to new cluster. But in all of this I am not sure if reindexing would be required or not, considering I create the indexes with same name as the old indexes ? Do you have any idea on this  ?

Comment: This should include this information already: "Snapshots are backups of a cluster's indices and state. State includes cluster settings, node information, index settings, and shard allocation."

Comment: That was the whole point of my question. It never talks about data. It talks about all the configs and settings but not the data.

Comment: These are covered under indices. The index includes the data for that index too :)